# Identify this tire

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Can anyone identify this tire in the photo below?  Looking for brand & part number.

It's black, rubber, narrow. Solid inside (no space for an inner tube). Slightly larger than 1" diameter.

There are no letters or numbers on it at all. I acquired it with a lot of building bricks, Lego and other, which is why I believe it may be related to one of the building brick brands.

[image]

Comment: Does it have LEGO markings anywhere on the tire? Your picture doesnt show any, which leads me to believe this is not a LEGO piece.

Comment: There are no markings anywhere, but I acquired it with bricks, Lego and otherwise.

Comment: I'd look for the hub/spoke piece it connects to.

Comment: This looks pretty much like a tire from the polish manufacturer Cobi. Are there any Cobi bricks in the collection you acquired?

Comment: While it's hard to prove a negative, the absence of any LEGO markings and the fact that this [list of all LEGO tires](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=111&itemBrand=1000&catType=P) does not contain this specific part points to it not being a LEGO part.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Jan, there were no Cobi parts. Do you have an image of the part you're referring to?  Zovits I agree but I wonder if it's a part from another brand.

Answer (score 5):

Although i'm not entirely sure, this might be a tire from Cobi

[image: Cobi Jeep]
[image: Cobi Kuebelwagen]